# Streaming video through RTSP

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, media, rtsp

I am trying to stream videos to Android via RTSP. The streaming works very well on Android 3.0 but for other lower versions the videos doesn't play.

I went through this link http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html and found out that h263 encoding is supported by android versions < 3.0.

I used Helix Producer to encode my video to h263 format and Helix Universal Server for streaming. The video plays smoothly on Android 3.0 but for all other lower versions it doesn't work.I am getting error "E/SW_DEC(31): PV SW DECODER is used for H.263" in logcat when I tried it on Android 2.1 emulator. I tested it on device as well but it doesn't work.

Is it a known issue?

Is there any specific supported video encoding parameters for Android 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode your videos with h.264. It's a better file format

Comment: I tried to encode my videos with h264, but the video didn't play on Android version < 3.0. I went to this link  http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html and found out that only h263 is supported by Android 2.1.

Comment: i had the same problems...android is poor in video formats. My solution was to upload the videos to youtube, and open from there. Youtube makes a compatible format somehow.